# org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: class configured for Signature (provider: BC) cannot be found

Tags: java, tomcat

I need some suggestions to resolve this issue, If any.

Issue here is, We are not able to create Partner Users after every deployment and If we restart tomcat service again then its works perfectly.

When we try to create Partner user after deployment we are getting below error on log.

```
20-Dec-2017 13:27:35.388 | ERROR | [   http-apr-28080-exec-78] | SecurityAdminServiceManagerImpl:1986 - Error in generateCertificateDetails 
org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: class configured for Signature (provider: BC) cannot be found.
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ~[bcpkix-jdk15on-156.jar:1.56.0.0]
    at com.northgateis.gem.security.cipher.CertificateHelper.signCertificate(CertificateHelper.java:298) ~[classes/:26696]
    at com.northgateis.gem.security.cipher.CertificateHelper.createClientCertificate(CertificateHelper.java:256) ~[classes/:26696]
    at com.northgateis.gem.security.service.impl.SecurityAdminServiceManagerImpl.generateCertificateDetails(SecurityAdminServiceManagerImpl.java:1979) [classes/:26696]

20-Dec-2017 13:56:44.158 INFO [http-apr-28080-exec-69] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi$SHA256]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi$SHA256]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1325)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
```

Comment: static {
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
 }
 
private static X509Certificate signCertificate(
   X509v3CertificateBuilder certificateBuilder,
   PrivateKey signedWithPrivateKey) throws OperatorCreationException,
   CertificateException {
  ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM)
    .setProvider(PROVIDER_NAME).build(signedWithPrivateKey);
  X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(
    PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certificateBuilder.build(signer));
  return cert;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you redeploy the app, like you do often while developing, it stops working. JNI is another thing which suffers from this problem.

I prefer shipping the jar with the app instead of having to manually copy it to the container lib directory.

You can add javapns.jar and bcprove-jdk15on-1.47.jar file in your lib folder

Add BouncyCastle to the JRE/JDK $`JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file as a provider (be sure that you add it to the JRE you use when running, eg. if you have multiple JRE's/JDK's installed)

Comment: But... Why it stops working? In our case, we ship BouncyCastle's jars with the app and it still has problems when deploying...