# Unable to load class 'org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

after new update on Android Studio , I'm getting this error:

> Unable to load class
> 'org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException'.
>
> This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log
> file.

even after creating new application, I'm still getting this error on running it.

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936839/org-bouncycastle-operator-operatorcreationexception-cannot-create-signer-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936839/org-bouncycastle-operator-operatorcreationexception-cannot-create-signer-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: class configured for Signature (provider: BC) cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936839/org-bouncycastle-operator-operatorcreationexception-cannot-create-signer-class)